# Почему спам-фильтры не пропускают письма с сайта?

Tags: php, sendmail

Интересно может кто-то для себя решил эту проблему Почему спам-фильтры mail.ru и подобных почтовиков не пропускают письма с сайта?

Конкретизирую: Письма например, подтверждения регистрации пользователя и подобные, которые направляються автоматически...

Comment: мы говорим о сферических письмах с сферического сервера?

Comment: Есть так называемые blacklist-списки ip-адресов, в которые попадают сервера, рассылающие спам. Спам-фильтры ориентируются в том числе и на них. Проверить, есть ли ip вашего сервера в этих списках можно, например, здесь - http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Если нашли - то либо меняйте хостинг, либо отправляйте письма через сторонние почтовые службы. Если не нашли - значит что-то не так с письмом.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у вас shared-хостинг и кто-то с этого ip-адреса занимается рассылкой спама. Возможный выход - приобрести выделенный ip-адрес.